# Convert imageUrl to byte[] for caching

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image that I capture from an ip camera and post it on a webpage to an image tag. Now I would like to convert to access the picture so that I can save it to our cache blob. Here is my code:

asp tag:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" />
```

code behind image assignment:

```
imgPhoto.ImageUrl = "http://10.10.40.35/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=640x480";
```

my attempt to convert the image to byte[]:

```
System.Drawing.Image _newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgPhoto.ImageUrl);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
_newImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] _fileBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
byte[] image = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(imgPhoto.ImageUrl);
```

Comment: The WebClient should be disposed (`using (var wc = new WebClient()) ...`)